# Hats--WInter Party Crasher

Tags: discussion

Are Hats the coolest thing ever that stacks have done?  Are there any particular hats for Politics?  What's with the Secret Hats and can we get a description of them? (I know, then they wouldn't be secret)

Comment: On the mother Meta: [Winter Bash 2016 - All Hats](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/288271/winter-bash-2016-all-hats) (including the secret ones)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no hats specific to the Politics site.

The only site that got specific hats was Stack Overflow and that is because they have products, Developer Story and Docs, that aren't available elsewhere.  But to offset those two hats, we made two hats that aren't available on Stack Overflow, Running Ragged and Polymath.

As far as secret hats, they are secret. We won't disclose all the triggers and descriptions until after 08 January, 2017, when the hats are put back in their boxes.